# Connecting FTDI device to Android as VCP

Tags: java, android, serial-port, ftdi, d2xx

I'm trying to connect an FTDI FT2232H to an Android application using the Java class library that FTDI provides, which does not require root access.

Is there a way to use VCP through this package, rather than the old-style native driver route? Or, if not, is there a way to emulate a VCP interface through it (or is it possible at all to roll my own solution?) I'm finding the official docs a bit lacking, as they encourage using the Java lib over the native one, but don't explain whether or not it provides full feature parity.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use VCP through [D2XX](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Android_Java_D2XX_2.08.zip) driver. Take a look at [Java D2xx for Android API User Manual](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_233_Java_D2xx_for_Android_API_User_Manual.pdf) (also at C/C++ [Software Application Development D2XX Programmer's Guide](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf) and [FTD2XX Programmer’s Guide
Version 2.01](http://www.dlpdesign.com/drivers/D2XXPG21.pdf) documents), [Official Android D2XX Example Source code](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android/TN_147_Java_D2xx_for_Android_Demo_Source.zip) especially at `FT2232HTestFragment.java` class from it:

> ```
> public void SendMessage(View view) {
>     // Do something in response to button
>     FT_Device ftDev;
>     if( uart_configured_0 == false ) {
>           Toast.makeText(DeviceFT2232HTestContext, "UART Port 0 not configured yet...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>           return;
>       }
>       ftDev = ft_device_0;
>
>       if(ftDev.isOpen() == false) {
>           Log.e(">>@@","SendMessage: ftDev not open!!!!!!  index: 0");
>       } else {
>           Log.e(">>@@","SendMessage: ftDev open, index: 0");
>
> /*            Log.e(">>@@","port 0 isn:" + ftDev.deviceInfoNode.iSerialNumber
>                   + " bcd:" + ftDev.deviceInfoNode.bcdDevice
>                   + " id:" + ftDev.deviceInfoNode.id
>                   + " loc:" + ftDev.deviceInfoNode.location
>                   + " sn:" + ftDev.deviceInfoNode.serialNumber);
> */        
>     }
>
>   ftDev.setLatencyTimer((byte) 16);
>
>   // ftDev.Purge(true, true);
>
>   String writeData = writeText_0.getText().toString();
>   byte[] OutData = writeData.getBytes();
>   int iLen = ftDev.write(OutData, writeData.length());
>   Log.e(">>@@", "Port 0 write Len:" + iLen + " s:" + writeData);
>   Toast.makeText(DeviceFT2232HTestContext,
>           "Port 0 write Len:" + iLen + " s:" + writeData,
>           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> }
> ```

and examples like [that](https://github.com/ksksue/Android-FTDI-UART-Sample) (by [Keisuke SUZUKI](https://github.com/ksksue)).